# Android Animation Bug wont let me click after animation move to the right

Tags: java, android

So, here's my problem? I have it where it will slide out and then it will stay in that position and then you should be able to click on it again and it will slide back to the original location.

But instead I have to click on where it FIRST was at. Even when it's slided out. I want to make it after the animation I can click it any where, that it slided out.

Here's my code

```
   public void sideBar()
   {

       ImageView sidebar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sidebar);

       if(out == 0)
       {
       mSlideInRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_right);
       mSlideInRight.setFillAfter(true);
       sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInRight);
       out= 1;
       }
       else if(out == 1)
       {
               mSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in_left);
               sidebar.startAnimation(mSlideInLeft);
               out=0;
       }

   }
```

and this is the code for when you click on it

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView sidebar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sidebar);
         ImageView popup = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.popup);
         ImageView popup2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.popup2);

        switch(v.getId())
        {           
            case R.id.sidebar:
                sideBar();
            break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Animations only affect how your sidebar `ImageView` is drawn, not its actual position. After your animation completes, you should update the sidebar's layout parameters to your desired position. You can do this in an `AnimationListener` if you want the position to be updated as the animation runs or after it is complete, or right after your call to `startAnimation` if you want the position change to happen as the animation starts.

```
mSlideInRight.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {};

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {};

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(...);
        // Set properties of layoutParams here
        sidebar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    };
});
```

Replace `RelativeLayout` with whatever layout your ImageView is a child of.

Comment: Could you give me a example on how I would do this?

Comment: I'm still pretty confused. Could you please update the code that it would go with mine? What do you mean "whatever layout your ImageView is a child of"

Comment: Add the code I posted before you run startAnimation. Your ImageView is a child of some layout as defined in XML, or elsewhere in your code. I'd suggest giving http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html a read.